# Why is my Ubuntu Linux box telling me it can't find pygame and pygcurse?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, pygame

I'm working on a game in python that requires pygame and pygcurse. It appears they're both installed. I have pygame installed with apt-get, and I have pygcurse installed as a lib locally.

```
root@blog:~/dan-game# apt-get install python-pygame
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pygame is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
root@blog:~/dan-game# ls -l
total 2248
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12574 Jan 18 21:49 cat.png
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jan 18 23:04 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   112507 Sep 10  2011 pygcurse.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      144 Jan 18 21:49 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      166 Jan 18 21:49 save.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    13360 Jan 18 22:35 the-word-of-elements.py


root@blog:~/dan-game# python3 the-word-of-elements.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "the-word-of-elements.py", line 14, in <module>
import pygcurse
File "/root/dan-game/pygcurse.py", line 58, in <module>
import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Curious if anyone knows why my import pygame and import pygcurse are throwing errors? I wonder if it's because python3 can't see the libs, but apt-get has installed the lib for python 2.x instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Quite possible.  pygcurse is actually starting to import fine, it's just it can't find pygame.  If you have `pip3` try using that to install pygame for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Ubuntu (trusty, utopic, vivid, ...) provide [python-pygame 1.9.1* package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pygame&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), which does not support Python-3.x.

According to [PyGame FAQ](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Does%20Pygame%20work%20with%20Python%203?):

> **Does Pygame work with Python 3?**
>
> Yes. Pygame **1.9.2** supports Python 3.2 and up. Only the orphaned _movie
>   module (not built by default) does not.

(emphasis by me)

You may need to build pygame yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`import pygcurse` is likely failing because this syntax has been deprecated for relative imports as of Python 3.

From https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax:

> The only acceptable syntax for relative imports is `from .[module] import name`. All import forms not starting with `.` are interpreted as absolute imports. (PEP 0328)

As for why `import pygame` is failing, it appears that as of version 1.9.2 pygame supports Python 3, but the current stable release provided by Ubuntu is version 1.9.1. From the [pygame faq](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Miscellaneous):

> Does Pygame work with Python 3?
>
> Yes. Pygame 1.9.2 supports Python 3.2 and up. Only the orphaned _movie module (not built by default) does not.

You may have to download and build version 1.9.2 from source, rather than installing it through Apt.

Comment: Thanks, I compiled pygame on 1.9.2 and all is well now.